# Notice: Array to string conversion in pathname on line 33 Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, dynamic, fetch

I continually get the notice, "Notice: Array to string conversion in pathname on line 33". When I hide the notice though `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` I still get the word "Array" appearing as many times as rows I have returning. Being new I can't seem to get rid of them. There error in code is somewhere around here.

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT * FROM NETWORK';

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $rows["network"][] = $r;
}

print json_encode($rows);
?>
```

When I test this on the browser it returns this.

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/dl.php on line 33
Array
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/dl.php on line 33
Array
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/dl.php on line 33
Array
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/dl.php on line 33
Array
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/dl.php on line 33
Array
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/dl.php on line 33
Array
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/dl.php on line 33
Array
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/dl.php on line 33
Array
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/dl.php on line 33
Array
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/dl.php on line 33
Array
{"network":[{"lid":"1","sid":"1","player_id":"1","active":"1"},
{"lid":"1","sid":"1","pid":"4","active":"1"},
{"lid":"1","sid":"2","pid":"2","active":"1"}, 
{"lid":"1","sid":"2","pid":"5","active":"1"},
{"lid":"1","sid":"3","pid":"3","active":"1"},
{"lid":"2","sid":"1","pid":"1","active":"1"},
{"lid":"2","sid":"2","pid":"2","active":"1"},
{"lid":"2","sid":"2","pid":"4","active":"1"},
{"lid":"2","sid":"3","pid":"3","active":"1"},
{"lid":"2","sid":"3","pid":"5","active":"1"}]}
```

The overall question is what am I doing wrong? But because I get the notice and not an error I assume maybe nothing is wrong but maybe there is a better way to get the final outcome I want, which is the array encoded with json. All and Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `echo`. `$r` is an array not a string and can't be used with `echo`:

```
//echo $rows["network"][] = $r;
$rows["network"][] = $r;
```

And why do you build `$rows` but `json_encode` `$rows3`?

Comment: Thanks it totally worked. Sorry the $row3 I forgot to change, to make the code easier to read. I coped that part from a different place on the file so it was just a transposition error.